# How can I use a Django F() expression in TastyPie's hydrate cycle?

Tags: python, django, tastypie, race-condition

I have a model with a version number in it. I want it to self-increment when new data is posted with an existing `id` via TastyPie. I'm currently doing this via the hydrate method, which works as long as two users don't try to update at once:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    ...
    def hydrate_version(self, bundle):
        if 'id' in bundle.data:
            target = self._meta.queryset.get(id=int(bundle.data['id']))
            bundle.data['version'] = target.version+1
        return bundle
```

I'd like to do this more robustly by using [Django's F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields), e.g.:

```
    def hydrate_version(self, bundle):
        if 'id' in bundle.data:
            from django.db.models import F
            target = self._meta.queryset.get(id=int(bundle.data['id']))
            bundle.data['version'] = F('version')+1
        return bundle
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ExpressionNode'
```

Is there a way to more robustly increment the version number with TastyPie?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would override the save() method for your Django Model instead, and perform the update there.  That has the added advantage of ensuring the same behavior regardless of an update from tastypie or from the django/python shell.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.version = F('version') + 1

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks - that sounds sensible.  Strangely when I implement this, I get the same error in my unit tests (which are subclassed from `tastypie.test`'s `ResourceTestCase`) whenever I save an instance of the model. However when I enter a python shell and save an instance, it's fine. Is there a problem with unit tests and F() expressions?

Comment: I've looked into this further: first, in the `save` method above, I needed to add `if self.pk is not None:`, so that on new instances the `F()` expression is not used. Second, I wrote a unit test which directly saves the instance using `my_model.save()`, and this works fine. However the unittest which updates the model through the API continues to give me an error in the TastyPie `fields.py` `dehydrate` method.  I suspect the problem is the F() expression remains unevaluated in the instance that TastyPie is trying to return; I need to somehow force TastyPie to re-get the instance after saving.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered at [github here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/1003#issuecomment-37314339), though I haven't tried this myself yet.  To quote from that link:

> You're setting bundle.data inside a hydrate method. Usually you modify bundle.obj in hydrate methods and bundle.data in dehydrate methods.
>
> Also, those F objects are meant to be applied to Django model fields.
>
> I think what you want is:

```
def hydrate_version(self, bundle):
    if bundle.obj.id is not None:
        from django.db.models import F
        bundle.obj.version = F('version')+1
    return bundle
```